# Infrastructure for QUnit and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

I'm familiar with Unit Testing and JUnit in particular when it comes to Java.  The group in which I work will be starting a project in which I want to use QUnit while developing JavaScript.

I want to set up an infrastructure such that members of the team will be able to write QUnit tests which will be able to run by going to a single page.  In Java I put a class under a package, for example, com.abc.MyClass and I have a separate project which contains the same package with a test class MyClassTest.

Maybe somebody can help me project this infrastructure setup to JavaScript.  I know to some degree about JavaScript namespace best practice.  Maybe somebody has ideas how to set up an infrastructure?

Comment: Note: You may want to go back and [accept answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) for your previous questions. It will encourage people to help you in the future.

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing, SBel.  It's all great that some people hook up HTML files, etc., but the real question is, where do these artifacts go?  Do they belong in a separate package/project?  Is this HTML page supposed to be inside the web app itself?

Answer (score 0):

We use an HTML file like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"> 
    <head>
        <title>All Unit Tests</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" /> 
        <link media="screen" href="qunit.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="qunit.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="allOurCode.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="unitTests.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="qunit-header">All Unit Tests</h1>
        <h2 id="qunit-banner"></h2>
        <div id="qunit-testrunner-toolbar"></div>
        <h2 id="qunit-userAgent"></h2>
        <ol id="qunit-tests"></ol>
        <div id="qunit-fixture">Test markup--will be hidden</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

allOurCode.js and unitTests.js are pre-generated using a shell script; they are just concatenations of all the source code and all the unit tests, respectively.

I can't think of a solution that doesn't involve running the shell script first, but you do end up with a single web page to visit.